# jQuery Mobile Default Swatches

Tags: jquery-mobile

Let me start off by saying I'm new to jQuery mobile.  I've been asked to change to theme of a website and from looking at the jQuery mobile website [here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/api/themes.html) there is 5 default swatches that come with it.  The only problem is that when I look at the theme file it only has 2 swatches, labeled A and B, but which look more like A and C.  Can someone tell me where I can find the additional default swatches?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: which jqm version are you using?

Comment: jQM 1.4 has only A and B, the rest you need to create them using ThemeRoller. http://themeroller.jquerymobile.com/ you can load A & B, and add more swatches. on toolbar bar above, click _import_ and then _import default themes_ on the popup that shows.

Comment: OIC, well that sucks.  Is it possible to use a theme file from an older version?

Comment: surely you can, _import_ old files then upgrade them.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!  If you want to right your comments as an answer I will gladly give you credit for answering the question.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Mobile 1.4 has two themes "a" and "b", unlike previous versions.

To upgrade custom themes previously created by [ThemeRoller](http://themeroller.jquerymobile.com/), at the page's top, click on *import* to upload old themes and then choose *1.4.0* from drop-down *Upgrade to version* list.

Answer (score 2):

The guys from jQuery mobile also created the classic theme for 1.4 although they don't actually support it.

You can find it here: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/theme-classic/theme-classic.css
And view the demo here: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/theme-classic/